# Transpile Typescript without CLI

Tags: node.js, typescript

How can I transpile Typescript without using the command line?

I want to have a script `build.js` that will build my application.

So far, I found that the `typescript` package has a `transpile(inputArgument, compileOptions)` method, but I couldn't find anything about this on their documentation.

I can have my project built using `tsc -p server`, so I imagined the following would work:

```
const tsc = require('typescript');

tsc.transpile("", {
    project: "server",
});
```

Then I'd use `node build.js`.

I couldn't get the `tsc.transpile()` to work (I couldn't figure out what the `inputArgument` was) and I couldn't find on their documentation how to do this: transpile from code, without the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html)module

In your case:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const ls = spawn('tsc', ['-p', 'server']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but it does solve the problem. Thank you